# how to set both horizontal and vertical layout params programmatically

Tags: android, layoutparams

In xml file we can do;

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
```

I couldn't find how to set those params programmatically. I think something like this is not possible.

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER;
```

Comment: Anyone knows how to do this in Kotlin? This line gives me an error
Edit: Nevermind, just found. 
`params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL`